# panel doesn't want to scroll

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jcomponent

I have this piece of code (a panel that contains other `JComponent`s, in this case `JButton`s) and a problem.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JTagPanelTest extends JPanel{

    public JTagPanelTest(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 2, 0));
    }

    public void initializeTags(List<String> tags){
        tags.forEach(tag -> add(new JButton(tag)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            try{
                String lookAndFeelName = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lookAndFeelName);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JTagPanelTest test = new JTagPanelTest();
            test.initializeTags(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten",
                "012", "qwer", "z<xc", "rty", "poiu", "gfj", "zxcv", "mjnb", "mko", "nij", "bhu"));
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(test);
            scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBar(null);
            test.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
//          scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 180));
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
            frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(new Dimension(200, 180));
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}
```

I though it was enough to put my `JTagPanelTest` inside a `JScrollPane` to make it scrolling but it's not so, and I really don't know why.

It was of no use calculating the final height of the internal panel, as it results `0`.

Note that the number of `JButton`s are not fixed, so the panel has to be scrollable in order to show all the "buttons".

Is there someone who can make me aware of my mistake?

Thank you

Comment: Note all Swing components should be created on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). So all the code, not just the setVisible(...) should be part of the `invokeLater(...)`

Comment: This `test.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));` artificially constrains the test JPanel's size. You most definitely do *not* want to do this.

Comment: If I remove that line the buttons does not wraps at the edge of the panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried the right approach by setting preferred size on `scrollPane`.

So revert to that change. The reason it is not scrolling is because your content is not added to align vertically. Set a layout the helps add items vertically.

For example:

```
test.setLayout(new BoxLayout(test, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
//test.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 180));
```

Comment: thank you so much!!
... but in this manner all the buttons appears in column... is there a way to have a list of buttons that wraps at the right edge of the panel and possibly extends vertically?

Answer (score 0):

I've also found [this code](https://github.com/mgarin/weblaf/blob/master/modules/ui/src/com/alee/extended/layout/HorizontalFlowLayout.java) that resolves the problem of vertical stacked components. And [this one](http://www.camick.com/java/source/WrapLayout.java).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want the buttons to wrap, hence you add them to a `JPanel` that uses the `FlowLayout` layout manager. I also understand that you want the `JPanel` containing those buttons to scroll. I achieved this by setting the preferred sizes of the `JScrollPane` and the `JPanel` containing the buttons, as shown in the below code.

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class BtnScrl implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private void showGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BtnScrl");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createButtons());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JScrollPane createButtons() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 290));
        for (String tag : Arrays.asList("one",
                                        "two",
                                        "three",
                                        "four",
                                        "five",
                                        "six",
                                        "seven",
                                        "eight",
                                        "nine",
                                        "ten",
                                        "012",
                                        "qwer",
                                        "z<xc",
                                        "rty",
                                        "poiu",
                                        "gfj",
                                        "zxcv",
                                        "mjnb",
                                        "mko",
                                        "nij",
                                        "bhu")) {
            panel.add(new JButton(tag));
        }
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
        return scrollPane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new BtnScrl());
    }
}
```

Here is a screen capture of the running app.

[image: BtnScrl]

Comment: After a few tries with your code I came to the conclusion that the scrollpane scrolls because you added the line ```panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 290));```, and I don't know the height of the overall panel beforehand.

Comment: @maurotrev You can calculate the preferred size based on the sizes of the buttons. Or you can set an arbitrary size which is what `JTable` does. These are not the only options available. If there are details you wish to add to your question, you can. All you need to do is [edit] your question. Note that I did write in my answer that I set the preferred sizes of both the `JPanel` and the `JScrollPane`.